# Call a specific button onClick event when the enter key is pressed C#

Tags: c#, onclick, keypress, enter

I'm trying to get a specific asp:button onclick event to fire when I press the enter key in a specific asp:textbox control.

The other factor to be taken into account is that the button is within a asp:Login control template.

I've no idea how to do this, suggestions on a postcard please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could look at the [`DefaultButton`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.panel.defaultbutton.aspx) property of the panel control.

Answer (score 2):

You could set the DefaultButton property on the form. Either as an attribute of the form tag in your markup DefaultButton = "btnSubmit" or using something like this in your code-behind:

```
Page.Form.DefaultButton = "btnSubmit"
```

Answer (score 1):

Its [HtmlForm.DefaultButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlform.defaultbutton(VS.80).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it with javascript. It's really easy with [jQuery.](http://jquery.com/)

You can do something like (off the top of my head, not tested):

```
$('#myTextBox').keypress(function(e){
    if(e.which == 13)
        $('#myBtn').click();
});
```

Edit: Be aware that although jQuery works exceptionally cross browser, there are some quirks with keypress described [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/keypress).

Whoops i didnt see you said the "enter key" i thought you said "any key", yeah in that case use DefaultButton on asp:panel

Comment: You don't need to do this with javascript.